# How to change a Magento version in admin?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, design

I want to know how to change this text at the bottom of the admin panel Magento. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this might be used to deceive anyone into thinking they have another version than the one they have. Will gladly remove my vote if the use case is not this.

Comment: I've worked with Magento installations in the past where eager developers tried to hide as much Magento-ish data from the admin to hide the fact that they're running Magento. It's a 90's thing I guess. Makes debugging a pain because you have to check `Mage.php` for the version number... However... I can imagine that there are still some developers out there who are interested in how to remove useful information from the footer. I'll vote to keep this open.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that Magento Version line in Adminhtml Template.

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/footer.phtml
```

around **line 36**

```
<?php echo $this->__('Magento ver. %s', Mage::getVersion()) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the translation of this text intead of doing overrides. 
You can translate it from the csv files.

check this tutorial how to do it https://belvg.com/blog/editing-magento-translate-csv-file.html